# How to delete Child Table record With parent key In hibernate Annotation.?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

i am using hibernate annotation and Mysql for database.
I have Two Table One is Purchaser Table and Other one is CashReceipt. CashReciept has a reference key on Purchaser table.

so how can i delete a record of CashReceipt for specific Purchaser?

i have tried this query

```
session.createQuery("Delete FROM CashReceipt cr LEFT JOIN cr.purchase p WHERE p.id=:sid")
                .setInteger("sid", purchase.getId()).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer by trying this query.

```
 session.createQuery("Delete FROM CashReceipt cr WHERE cr.purchase.id=:sid")
                            .setInteger("sid", purchase.getId()).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I would like to knowso you set on delete cascade on creating two tables

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it manually when you can use session.delete like :

```
SomeEntity ent = session.get(SomeEntity.class, '1234');
session.delete(ent);
```

Also you may want to look at CascadeType for your parent table. Set it to CascadeType.DELETE in your parent table.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DELETE)
List<Child> childElements;
```

It will delete all child elements associated with that parent.

Comment: because by This i can delete only single record in table where in my case i have thousand of record in cashReceipt Table which are associated with particular purchaser.